# Copula: How to solve Integral with minimum for computation of Spearmans rho

Tags: definite-integrals

How can you calculate Spearman's rho of the comonotinicity copula?

Comonotonicity Copula: $Cm(u1, u2) = min(u1, u2)$

Spearmans rho: $\rho = 12 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} C(u1,u2) du1 du2 -3$

Obviously, this results in the following: $12 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} min(u1, u2)  du1 du2 -3$

But how can I solve this integral with a minimum?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with the help of the following post:

user21436, integrals involving minimum function, URL (version: 2012-02-05): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105854

$$\begin{align*}\int_o^t\int_0^t \min\{x,y\} \mathrm dy ~~\mathrm dx&=\dfrac{t^3}{3}\end{align*}$$

$$12 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} min\{u1, u2\}  du1 du2 -3 = 12 * 1^3/3 -3 = 1$$